# Python3 - 2 functions that don't work as inner-functions, life assistance needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape for a personal project. Whenever I attempt to condense the code into either one function, or create two inner functions as shown below, I don't receive anything back. However, when I expand the functions out on their own, they work just fine.

Works:

```
import requests
import os
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser_headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137"}

def iata_sing(city):
    starting_letter = city[0].upper()
    iata_single = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_airport_code:_{starting_letter}"
    sin_city = requests.get(url=iata_single, headers=browser_headers)
    sin_city.raise_for_status()
    sin_soup = BeautifulSoup(sin_city.content, 'html.parser')
    main = sin_soup.find('div', id='content').find_all('td')
    for line in main:
        if "title=" and city.title() in line.text:
            iata = line.findPreviousSibling().findPreviousSibling()
            iata_target = list(iata)[0]
            # print(iata_target)
            return iata_target

def iata_multi(city):
    iata_multiple = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code#Cities_with_multiple_airports"
    airport_list = []
    city = city.title()
    cities = requests.get(url=iata_multiple, headers=browser_headers)
    cities.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cities.content, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup.prettify())
    s = soup.find('div', id='content')
    body = s.find('div', class_='mw-parser-output')
    ULs = body.find_all('li')
    for line in ULs:
        if city in line.text:
            for item in line.text:
                airport_list.append(item)
    new_list = "".join(airport_list)
    return new_list

# print(iata_multi("paris"))
print(iata_sing("leigh"))
```

Doesn't work and not sure why, but a single call is preferable.:

```
def iata(city):

    browser_headers = {
        "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137"}

    def iata_sing(city):
        starting_letter = city[0].upper()
        iata_single = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_airport_code:_{starting_letter}"
        sin_city = requests.get(url=iata_single, headers=browser_headers)
        sin_city.raise_for_status()
        sin_soup = BeautifulSoup(sin_city.content, 'html.parser')
        main = sin_soup.find('div', id='content').find_all('td')
        for line in main:
            if "title=" and city.title() in line.text:
                iata = line.findPreviousSibling().findPreviousSibling()
                iata_target = list(iata)[0]
                # print(iata_target)
                return iata_target

    def iata_multi(city):
        iata_multiple = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code#Cities_with_multiple_airports"
        airport_list = []
        city = city.title()
        cities = requests.get(url=iata_multiple, headers=browser_headers)
        cities.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cities.content, 'html.parser')
        # print(soup.prettify())
        s = soup.find('div', id='content')
        body = s.find('div', class_='mw-parser-output')
        ULs = body.find_all('li')
        for line in ULs:
            if city in line.text:
                for item in line.text:
                    airport_list.append(item)
        new_list = "".join(airport_list)
        return new_list

    try:
        iata_multi(city)
        iata_sing(city)
    except IndexError:
        print("This appears to be a multi-airport location")

iata("paris")
```

So far I've attempted to separate each function out (which works) but whenever I create a single function, be that with 2 inner functions, or just removing the function definitions and using the code, I don't get a reply, and I'm kind of stuck as to the reason.

Comment: Your first code never uses `iata_multi()`, the call is commented out. What's the point of it? The second code calls the inner functions, but never uses the results. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: so as per @Barmar try second code adding: print(iata("paris"))

Comment: @pippo1980 That won't help. `iata()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Put `print()` around the calls to the inner functions.

Comment: or add some return after calls after try

Comment: Thanks for replying, re: the first functions, they work, I've just commented one out while testing.

re the second set, yes, I forgot to put in the print statement on the call for this question, however I have tested it with the print statement in: print(iata("Paris")) 
even then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar - You got it! thank you, I put a print statement on the inner calls:

try:
    print(iata_multi(city))
    print(iata_sing(city))
except IndexError:
    print("This appears to be a multi-airport location")

Comment: @pippo1980 You can only return once, so if he returns the first call it won't return the second one.

Comment: Pretty sure I could return like this if required:

return iata_multi(city), iata_sing(city)

Comment: @Barmar yep sure, in my online compiler example I was returning a +b (a = iata_sing, b = iata_multi)

Answer (score 0):

Put print() around the calls to the inner functions. – Barmar

As Barmar stated, this worked:

```
try:
    print(iata_multi(city))
    print(iata_sing(city))
except IndexError:
    print("This appears to be a multi-airport location")
```

Thank you!